# want to fix the issue without height attributr

Tags: css

I have a div and implemented a image slider inside it.i did not gave height for this, because i want to make this responsive.But the bottom div over lapping with this .I thik its the issue of height.How can i solve this with out give height for the top div

```
<div class="img_box">
  <div class="banner_controls"></div>
<div class="banner_slider ">
  <a onclick="javascript:void(0);" href="javascript:void(0);">
<img title="" alt="" src="images/cafe_sierraimg_bannerimg1.jpg" />
</a>
<a onclick="javascript:void(0);" href="javascript:void(0);" >
<img title="" alt="" src="images/cafe_sierraimg_bannerimg2.jpg" /> 
</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bottom div

```
<div class="small_box_green"> <span class="arrow_default right"></span> <span class="triangle_greentop"></span>
    <h2>Join us!</h2>
    Enjoy California 
    Continental Pacific Rim and Chinese dishes at our award-winning Café Sierra in a light and breezy setting for breakfast, lunch and dinner.</div>
```

css

```
.img_box {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.small_box_green {
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(164, 179, 81, 0.7);
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: it's not overlapping in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/G5Tz6/

Comment: there is a image slider inside the div, thats making the issue

Comment: when i give height for any of that div it will be fix, but i want to make it responsive